# Porting sched.h to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, header-files, porting

I am going to port linux program into windows. but I do not know what is the equivalent to sched.h header in Windows. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 2):

[libpthread](https://code.google.com/p/libpthread/) is an implementation of POSIX threads for Windows.

It contains a `sched.h` compliant to that part of POSIX.

You can see its source [here](https://code.google.com/p/libpthread/source/browse/include/sched.h).

Comment: once I used that, there is unresolved external error due to the function sched_setscheduler().

Answer (score 0):

You should use either MinGW or Cygwin as environment for the program, and then compile it newly with gcc from this toos. Then it runs under Windows. The difference is: API to the OS. MinGw and Cygwin offer an Unix-API running on Windows.
The other possibility is, but only for non-PC-Programming: I have created an own OSAL level (Operation System Adaption Level) and implement OS accesses both for Linux and Windows. I can run the Linux adaption with GCC or Cygwin under Windows, but can also run immediately with the WIndows-OSAL version. But this OSAL is for embedded programming, to adapt any embedded environment to the programs. It is not for typical PC programs. See https://vishia.org/emc